# Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("<input name= "searchtext" [(ngModel)]="searchtext">

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-pipe, pipes-filters

I am trying to do filter a number from a number array. but I got this errors.this a my codes.

app.module.ts

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NumberFilterPipe } from './number-filter.pipe';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { StringFilterPipe } from './string-filter.pipe';
import { NumberFilterService } from './service/number-filter.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NumberFilterPipe,
    StringFilterPipe
],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    NumberFilterService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

this the my html

```
<input  name= "searchtext"  [(ngModel)]="searchtext">
{{searchtext}}
<li *ngFor = "let numbers of number | number-filter : searchtext ">{{numbers}}</li>
<br><br>
```

this the pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { NumberFilterService } from './service/number-filter.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'number-filter'
})
export class NumberFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

flterNumber: NumberFilterService;

  transform(numbers: any, key: any): any[] {



    return this.flterNumber.filterNumber(numbers, key);


  }

}
```

and this the service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class NumberFilterService {

    arrayLen = 0;
    itteration = 0;
    result = [];
    constructor() { }
    filterNumber(values: any[], key: any): any[] {
        this.arrayLen =  values.length;
        for (this.itteration = 0 ; this.itteration < this.arrayLen ; this.itteration ++  ) {
            if (key === values[this.itteration]) {
                this.result.push(values[this.itteration]);
            }

        }
        return this.result;
    }

}
```

and I got this errors.

```
"Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("<input  name= "searchtext"  [(ngModel)]="searchtext">
{{searchtext}}
<li [ERROR ->]*ngFor = "let numbers of number | number-filter : searchtext ">{{numbers}}</li>
<br><br>"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@2:4
Parser Error: Unexpected token -, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 31 in [let numbers of number | number-filter : searchtext ] in ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@2:4 ("l)]="searchtext">
{{searchtext}}
<li *ngFor = "let numbers of number | number-filter : searchtext ">[ERROR ->]{{numbers}}</li>
<br><br>"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@2:67
    at syntaxError (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:684)
    at TemplateParser.parse (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:24547)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:33975)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:33950)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:33852)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:33852)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:33722)
    at Object.then (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:673)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:33721)"
```

I hope your valuable solution for this.thanks all . Have a nice day.

Comment: Try using another name for your pipe like  `let numbers of number | numberFilter : searchtext`

Comment: are you said change the pipe name ?

Comment: Yes, `@Pipe({
  name: 'numberFilter'
})`

Comment: And why not `let number of numbers`?

Comment: I changed it. its but another error. TypeError: Cannot read property 'filterNumber' of undefined
    at NumberFilterPipe.transform

Comment: Should `flterNumber: NumberFilterService;` be imported in constructor through DI?

Comment: Where is `toUpperCase` function in your code?

Comment: @smartmouse Angular parses ngFor expression and raises that error

Comment: Check my answer ...you are trying wrong thing

Comment: Hi, Let me know if you requried code I can provide you that also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this way its working

Pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: 'myfilter'
})

export class MyFilter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], term: any[]): any {
    if (!term)
      return items;
    return items.filter(item => item == term);
  }
}
```

component template

```
<input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="term" placeholder="filter by prefix" />
<li *ngFor="let product of listA  | myfilter:term" >{{product}}</li>
```

component ts

```
  val:number ;
  listA = [1,20,11,99];
```

---

**Final update which is working**

Below is fully tested and working

*html template file*

```
<input name="searchtext" [(ngModel)]="searchtext" (ngModelChange)="fitlerNumbers()" > {{numbers|json}}
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let number of numbers|numberfilter:2">{{number}}</li>
</ul>
```

*pipe.ts file*

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { NumberFilterService } from './NumberFilterService';

@Pipe({
  name: 'numberfilter'
})
export class NumberFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(public servicenum : NumberFilterService){}

  transform(numbers: any[], key: any ): any[] {
    return this.servicenum.filterNumber(numbers,key);

  }
}
```

*Filter SErvice file*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class NumberFilterService {

    arrayLen = 0;
    itteration = 0;
    result = [];
   public filterNumber(values: any[], key: any): any[] {
        this.arrayLen =  values.length;
        for (this.itteration = 0 ; this.itteration < this.arrayLen ; this.itteration ++  ) {
            if (key === values[this.itteration]) {
                this.result.push(values[this.itteration]);
            }

        }
        return this.result;
    }
}
```

Updates end here

Comment: hi. thank you spend your valuable time for this. I want to do this with Pipes

Comment: @NaminduSanchila - i fixed your issue check my answer at the end where i fixed ....you need to pass vlaue in filter ...you cannot pass other element binding as input

Comment: @NaminduSanchila - still looking for how to fix your issue

Comment: yes. I have to doubt about two things.  01. you are passing filterNumber(number, key). in your service no arguments for that function. i am new for angular.

Comment: @NaminduSanchila - updated full soruce coce in my final update section of my answser, thigs are well tested and working fine ...please do accept answer and upvote if it works for you ..

Comment: I try to pass values from Pipe to my service and, I did all logics on service logic. then service return values to pipe , pipes to html template.

Answer (score 2):

problem in below line:
in your filter "number-filter" searchtext is not used but you are using in html.
thats the problem try "key" instead of "searchtext" in html

```
<li *ngFor = "let numbers of number | number-filter : searchtext ">{{numbers}}</li>
to
<li *ngFor = "let number of numbers | number-filter : key">{{numbers}}</li>
```

Comment: same error.. thanks you for spend your valuble time.